# How to use the default pip to install python packges to a specific virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, fabric

How to use pip to install software to a specific virtualenv from outside the virtualenv.

For example if I have a virtualenv /home/guest/virtualenv/django-env,
How to install python packages into /home/guest/virtualenv/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ without doing source /home/guest/virtualenv/django-env/bin/activate and by using the default pip available in /usr/local/bin/pip

The context is , I am doing remote installation of software using fabric , and when I am using fabric I am not able to persist newly created virtual env.
Hence , to be able to install software into the new virtualenv I am having to run the default  pip (/usr/local/bin/pip) from outside the virtualenv

Comment: do you use a bootstrap script? If so paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to source a virtualenv to use it. Just install the package by executing the pip that is installed in the virtualenv: `/home/guest/virtualenv/django-env/bin/pip install <package>`

You can also in earlier version of pip, run pip in another virtualenv than the one it's installed in with `pip -E`, like this:

```
pip -E /home/guest/virtualenv/django-env/
```

But that really has no advantage over the above, and could cause errors, so the first option is still better.

Comment: He/She needs to run the default pip (/usr/local/bin/pip). Though I'm not sure about the constraints.

Comment: @Babu: No, the OP *thinks* (s)he needs to run the default pip, as the OP thinks s(he) can't run the one in the virtualenv without first activating it. This is a misunderstanding.

Comment: It worked, I think I kind of missed the obvious, but nothing is obvious till somebody tells you its obvious :) , thanks @LennartRegebro for solving the actual problem rather than solving the immediate one (using default pip). It was precisely what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Previous to [pip 1.1](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/news.html#id5), there was an option -E to install packages inside an virtual environment without switching, like you can do,

```
pip install -E /path/to/env <package>
```

But according changelog,

> Removed -E/--environment option and PIP_RESPECT_VIRTUALENV; both use a
>   restart-in-venv mechanism that’s broken, and neither one is useful
>   since every virtualenv now has pip inside it. Replace pip -E
>   path/to/venv install Foo with virtualenv path/to/venv &&
>   path/to/venv/pip install Foo.

So if you have pip prior to 1.1, you're lucky to use the global pip.

Comment: First , I am a he (as if it matters) :) . My solution was what Lennart Regebro pointed out. But my lookout for the solution started with the -E option (I had some code which uses that, and it was not working with my pip (v 1.3) . Thanks @babu for pointing out the details.